# Как из apk файла сделать сборку Android App Bundle ?так как Playmarket не принимает мой файл

Tags: android, apk, android-bundle

Решил опубликовать первое приложение android , сделанное на React Native и гугл предлагает его оптимизировать и упаковать.
Только вот как это сделать- я не понял.
Подскажите, как опубликовать приложение и сделать сборку?

Comment: Не обязательно AppBundle публиковать. Однако, если вы уже согласились на это в консоли, то да, назад пути нет. Подпись уже будет не ваша и надо формировать AppBundle. Но врядли его можно сделать из APK. Надо выбирать AppBundle  как артефакт для сборки. Если ReactNative это не поддерживает, то тогда создавайте новый проект приложения в консоли, т.к. изменить уже ничего нельзя. И не верьте никогда гуглу, когда он что-то вам предлагает и советует.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб мне главное, что б приложение было в плеймаркете, а с бандлом оно или нет и больше весит или нет- вообще не важно. Так для этого нужно новое приложение создавать или как бандл сделать?

Comment: Самый лучший способ - создать новое приложение и отказаться от AppBundle и подписывание приложения гуглом. В этом случае, если вы потеряете ключ подписи - приложение нельзя будет обновить. Зато не надо AppBundle собирать и не будет гемороя с тестированием релизных сборок. Если всё это не важно - смотрите можно ли React Native приложение в AppBundle упаковать. Но я не думаю, что это возможно.